# Paragraph Component reporting via Views

Tags: 7, views

I would like to create a View that allows me to see where Paragraph Components are being utilised.

It would just need to be a basic tabular View consisting of the following fields:

- Paragraph Component Type / Name
- Parent Node Title
- Parent Node URL

Using exposed filters on the View it would then be ideally possible to filter by Paragraph Type so that you can easily see what nodes / pages are using what Paragraph Component Type / Name.

Is this possible through the Views UI? I have tried setting relationships between the node / field / entity, but can't get it to join up.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

1. Install the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module
2. Go to view and add a relationship in the advanced section
3. Search for your paragraph embed field and set the identifier as anything as you want
4. Add your paragraph fields by searching for the fields in the paragraph bundle
5. Click save and done!